# Como mudar fundo de uma imagem no código CSS com PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer o seguinte mudar o fundo de uma imagem de background img no css por dia da semana ou seja de segunda-feira a domingo de forma que para cada dia da semana apareça uma imagem diferente no background isso no código css como posso fazer isso usando php.

Obs: No caso preciso que esse fundo seja aplicado numa div como class pois esse fundos iram ser usados numa skin. Desde já agradeço quem poder me ajudar.

Comment: Se é só uma classe que queres mudar podes fazer isso no HTML que o PHP cria. Podes mostrar a linha do HTML/PHP oinde está esse código? quais são as classes que queres dar em que dia?

Comment: A class seria .skin_media e os dias da semana seriam Domindo, Segunda-Feira, Terça-Feira, Quarta-Feira, Quinta-Feira, Sexta-Feira e Sabado. E o código eu nem montei ele.

Comment: Mas em que elemento queres aplicar? `<img>`? `<div>`?

Comment: Numa div como class no caso pois a skin vai ser usada varias vezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber o numero do dia da semana podes usar o [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) assim:

```
$ds= date("w");
```

O domingo é numero `0`, segunda `1` e assim por diante. Desta maneira podes ter uma array com as imagens que queres usar:

```
$imagens = array('domingo.jpg', 'segunda.jpg', etc...);
```

e depois no teu código:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $imagens[$ds]; ?>)"></div>
```

Também podias ter uma classe para cada dia já preparadas no CSS, e na array do PHP teres os nomes dessas classes. Nesse caso usarias:

```
<div class="<?php echo $imagens[$ds]; ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: Grato pela ajuda no caso os itens da array iram ser postos seguindo a ordem de colocação na array no caso como são sete imagens vai pegar a primeira como domingo e da segunda a diante com demais dias da semana certo ? Se colocar mais de 7 no caso vai mudar do mesmo geito seguindo a ordem da array ate terminar o ciclo ?

Comment: @Rodrigo exato, domingo é `0`, segunda `1`, etc...

Comment: Se passar de 7 itens no caso eu colocar 14 imagens vai seguir o ciclo da array ate terminar ele de forma que a 8 imagem pega como domingo e da 9 imagem adiante os demais dias da semana ?

Comment: @Rodrigo quando usas `$imagens[$ds];` o `$ds` tem um numero de `0` a `7` e vai ser usado como indice da array. Vai escolher as imagens de 1 a 7 e vai voltar à primeira mesmo que tenhas mais imagens na array. Se tens mais imagens que 7 podes criar um algoritmo para sortear ou então saber o numero da semana do ano e ver se é par ou ímpar. Desse modo podes ler 14 imagens ciclicamente.